# Grouping four different divs into one

Tags: jquery, grouping

So I found this code below which groups div's:

```
var theDivs=  $('.testimonials');
var  numOfLines= theDivs.length;
for (i=0; i< numOfLines; i=i+3){
  theDivs.eq(i).add(theDivs.eq(i+1)).add(theDivs.eq(i+2)).wrapAll('<div class="slide" />') ;
}
```

It works lovely, but it only groups 3 divs, I'd like it to group 4.

I'm kicking myself about asking this question as I'm sure it's a very easy fix. I've tinkered with the numbers above, but just couldn't get it to work.

Greatly appreciate any assistance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try these changes

```
var theDivs=  $('.testimonials');
var  numOfLines= theDivs.length;
for (i=0; i< numOfLines; i=i+4){
  theDivs.eq(i).add(theDivs.eq(i+1)).add(theDivs.eq(i+2)).add(theDivs.eq(i+3)).wrapAll('<div class="slide" />') ;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

How about using [lt](http://api.jquery.com/lt) jquery method:

```
$(".testimonials:lt(4)").wrapAll('<div class="slide" />');
```

Or using [slice](http://api.jquery.com/slice/):

```
$('.testimonials').slice(0,5).wrapAll('<div class="slide" />');
```